# Gerrit time search operators is not working when specify to second

Tags: url, gerrit

If i'm using

`/changes/?q=status:merged+after:2018-08-25`

it can return the result,

however if using

`/changes/?q=status:merged+after:2018-08-25 00:00:00`

it returns `[]`

According to [document](https://github.com/gerrit-review/gerrit/blob/7d35ff3fbeddc22fd2e0b42ff3f971598bba0c25/Documentation/user-search.txt), it is able to search time like this.

`` [[after_since]]
after:'TIME'/since:'TIME'::
+
Changes modified after the given 'TIME', inclusive. Must be in the
format `2006-01-02[ 15:04:05[.890][ -0700]]`; omitting the time defaults
to 00:00:00 and omitting the timezone defaults to UTC. ``

How to query when specify time to second? Is my format of parameters wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using:

`/changes/?q=status:merged+after:2018-08-25 00:00:00`

only the `2018-08-25` part is being used as the `after:` value. The `00:00:00` part is being used as a free text query term.

The value of `after:` should be enclosed in quotes:

`/changes/?q=status:merged+after:"2018-08-25 00:00:00"`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting `400 Bad Request` errors when running:

```
/changes/?q=status:merged+after:2018-08-25 00:00:00
```

What solved it is to enclose the time in quotes, but I also needed to replace the space between the date and time with the plus sign. E.g.:

```
/changes/?q=status:merged+after:"2018-08-25+00:00:00"
```