# Gerrit Rest API not working when query string contains Hour, Minute, Second

Tags: rest, gerrit

With `curl` command and Gerrit Rest api, querying like below does not work well.

(Not OK)

/changes/?q=after:"2018-12-03 09:00:00"

Surely, without HH:MM:SS part, it works well.

(OK)

/changes/?q=after:"2018-12-03"

I found similar question in here: [Gerrit time search operators is not working when specify to second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031757/gerrit-time-search-operators-is-not-working-when-specify-to-second)

But the answer does not working.

Gerrit version is v2.13.7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Replace the space for "%20" is not enough.

Quotation mark also should be encoded as "%22".

If you add time zone also, you should encode "+" as "%2B" too.

Here is full working query string. Below query fetch changes which are updated after 2018-12-03 09:00:00.000 +0900.

```
/changes/?q=after:%222018-12-03%2009:00:00.000%20%2B0900%22
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace the space for "%20"